# JSF 2 with PrimeFaces: Incell-Editing, no updated object in RowEditEvent parameter

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm using Mojarra 2.0.3 on Tomcat 6.0 with Primefaces 2.

I got a dataTable and want to make it incell-editable. Everything works fine, but my rowEditListener with the parameter "RowEditEvent event" returns no new object.

```
public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent event) {
    Nutzer nutzer = (Nutzer) event.getObject(); // Get object from event
    System.out.println(nutzer.toString()); // This prints the OLD data,
                                           // not the data I wrote into the form
    nutzerManager.editNutzer(nutzer);      // Write into the database
}
```

The managed bean is in session scope. Why does the listener only receive the old data, not the data I wrote into the incell-formular?

Hope, you can help me.

Greets from germany,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake.

The getter for the tabledata loaded the data everytime out of the database.

```
private List<Nutzer> nutzerList;

public List<Nutzer> getNutzerList() {
    nutzerList = nutzerManager.getNutzer();
    return this.nutzerList;
}
```

This version is working:

private List nutzerList;

```
public List<Nutzer> getNutzerList() {
    if(nutzerList == null)
        nutzerList = nutzerManager.getNutzer();
    return this.nutzerList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you explain why it behaves like that? Can you describe "everytime"? Why tabledata loaded the data everytime out of the database?